I made sure she got her GED. | Does "make sure" mean the speaker succeeded in getting her to get a GED?
A woman is telling about how she helped a girl, who is now she is in conflict with. The woman says:
I helped her, made sure she got her GED, made sure that she was safe.
"....made sure..." caught my attention. I couldn't be sure whether the woman has achieved the result or not. Maybe we just can't know for sure how it ended.
So, by saying "I made sure she did this and that ....", can we just infer that she tried her best to have her get a GED (but we can't know for sure how it ended), or can we definitely know that she managed to get her to get a GED actually."

Question: Does "make sure" mean the speaker succeeded in getting her [some female person] to get a GED?
Answer: Yes, it does.
make sure
idiom
: to find out or do something so that one has no doubt about whether something is true, correct, will happen, etc.
Make sure (that) you turn the oven off.
They made sure everyone knew where they were supposed to be.
Merriam Webster
to take special care to do something:
Make sure you’re home by midnight.
Make sure to tell them I said "hi."
Cambridge Dictionary
make sure
phrase
If you make sure that something is done, you take action so that it is done.
Make sure that you follow the instructions carefully.
Collins Dictionary
I made sure to list three references.
If you make sure that someone does something, they have done it or did it. Because if they didn't, you'd say: I tried to make sure that etc.

Its meaning is quite loose in such contexts. It's one thing to make sure the door is locked, quite another to make sure that someone succeeds.  So much is involved in the latter that we can only say that the speaker devoted significant attention and effort towards that end.  The end was achieved.
The speaker is saying that she did what she could for that goal to be realized, and it was.

TimR, are you suggesting for instance that the sentence Kamala Harris made sure she won the 2024 presidential election is in fact accurate and true assuming that she did do everything in her power to get elected? I suggest you edit your answer to clarify that the end must come to pass.

@PaulTanenbaum Your example is a misuse of "made sure".  I don't think the speaker could say "I made sure she got her GED" if she never got the GED.  I thought I had made clear that the goal as reached with "The end was achieved" but I've added a second "And it was".

I agree, TimR, that my Kamala Harris example is a misuse of made sure. That was my point. All I am suggesting is that your answer be edited to state explicitly that the only situations in which it is appropriate to say that someone has made sure of a condition are those in which that condition has indeed come to pass.  What you currently say is that in the OP's example "the end was achieved." What would improve your answer would be to clarify that if the event hadn't been achieved, then made sure would not have been appropriate.

"make sure" in the present tense suggests effort but not 100% certainty. And the same in the imperative: "Make sure you get home by midnight" is an emphatic command. But in past tense I'd say it always means the outcome is certain.

@PaulTanenbaum: I think that's an effect of the simple past and is aspectual more than it is definitional.  A person could say *I was making sure she got her GED" and mean thereby "I was not being lax in my attentions and efforts to ensure that she completed the requirements for the GED" even if, in the end, she did not get the GED.  The verb "to make sure", when it involves guidance, coaching, parenting, managing, and so on, is not precise in its meaning and does not always entail success.

I was making sure the project came in under budget and on time.  --Right. I'm sure you were.

But TimR, in that case, a person could say *She was making sure she got elected president" and mean thereby "she was not being lax in her attentions and efforts to ensure that she completed the actions necessary to convince 51% of the voters" even if, in the end, she did not win the election.

Maybe, TimR, you're suggesting that the simple past made sure does imply the coming to pass, while the past progressive was making sure doesn't?

@PaulTanenbaum   The past progressive doesn't entail achievement of the goal, and the past simple does entail it but only  when the aspect is that of a discrete event or action -- not regular duties or activities.  I made sure she got to the train station on time that evening (goal achieved) versus I made sure incoming students  understood the town's view of underage drinking of alcoholic beverages. (not entailed)

made sure she got her GED, is most definitely successful. So is: make sure the door was locked. Otherwise, a person would say: I tried to make sure she got her GED or locked the door. There's nothing loose about it in the OP's sentence.

@Lambie. Nope (to borrow a phrase). A person can use "I made sure" when stating their job responsibilities.   "I made sure my clients were apprised of proposed changes in state and federal law that could affect their business" in which case it is not a specific act but an ongoing situation to which they had to respond. The meaning there is not the same as it is in "I made sure the door was locked."  What is "loose" about it in the OP's context is the nature of their actions, not whether the result was achieved. Read more carefully, please, before throwing your downvotes around.

I disagree with your answer. I made sure of something always means you were successful unless there's a caveat. I made sure she got her GED means she did get it. "I made sure my clients were apprised of proposed changes etc." means they were apprised of it. I mean how can one say differently unless one does say differently.

@Lambie If the person is the shipping manager for five years and in the course of that time  one package is lost somewhere in the warehouse, can they say of their duties "I made sure that shipments went out the door in  a timely manner"?  Yes, they can, because the meaning of the verb is not the same as it is in "I made sure the door was locked".  The meanings are not identical.

The meaning is the same. The package thing is a red herring.

@Lambie No, it's not a red herring. It is a usage of "made sure" to refer to regular duties rather than a specific act.  "The QA manager makes sure all product that leaves here is up to company standards."  It's a colloquialism for "has the oversight responsibility" which is not the same as making sure the door is locked.
